# Generating systematic incremental numbered filenames in Bash

Tags: linux, bash

I have a random number of files with names as:

```
id_1000.txt
id_2000.txt
id_3000.txt
id_4000.txt
```

Note that the number of `.txt` files varies in different directories. For example, a directory may contain only one `id_1000.txt` (at least) or may contain any number of files with any higher number of digits.

To convert the random number of filenames in systematic incremental number, I used following script in a *batch script*:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /a count=1
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b /od *.txt') do (
 echo ren "%%a" "id_!count!.txt"
 set /a count+=1
)
```

The output for the above input would be:

```
ren "id_1000.txt" "id_1.txt"
ren "id_2000.txt" "id_2.txt"
ren "id_3000.txt" "id_3.txt"
ren "id_4000.txt" "id_4.txt"
```

It first detects the number of `id_*.txt` files are there in the current directory, and then changes to the higher number with normal count order: 1, 2, 3, 4, etc. and echo a line.

Although I tried to search for alternative commands for Ubuntu,  I could not find any satisfactory result.

I am very new to the Linux  shell, any help in this matter will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: But the sample code you provided is batch programming. You want to run this use case in a Linux/Unix based machine or on a Windows machine?

Comment: I want to convert it in bash. I worked in windows machine previously, but cuurently migrating to linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
shopt -s globstar
n=0
for a in **/*.txt; do 
        ((n++))
        mv "$a" id_$n.txt
done
```

Comment: it works in my directory structure, one more question please, how can i print the generated  lines directely  in a separate file? I try >> file.txt, but bash gives permission denied

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have the following file system layout:

```
Dir
├── A
│   ├── id_1000.txt
│   ├── id_2000.txt
│   ├── id_3000.txt
│   └── id_4000.txt
├── id_5000.txt
├── id_6000.txt
├── id_7000.txt
└── id_8000.txt
```

Then you can use a script similar to the following:

```
let i=1
find "./Dir" -type f -regex '.*id_[0-9]+\.txt' | while read file
do
  mv "$file" "${file/%id_*.txt/id_$i}.txt"
  (( ++i ))
done
```

The script will rename the files as follows:

```
Dir
├── A
│   ├── id_1.txt
│   ├── id_2.txt
│   ├── id_3.txt
│   └── id_4.txt
├── id_5.txt
├── id_6.txt
├── id_7.txt
└── id_8.txt
```

The [`let` builtin](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/let) is used for arithmetic expressions. In the script above, we initialized `i` variable with value `1`.

The `find` command searches for files (`-type f`) in directory `./Dir` matching the [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) `'.*id_[0-9]+\.txt'` and outputs lines of the file paths. The output is connected with the `while` loop via [pipe](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-4.html). It means that the loop is connected to the other side of the pipe, and reads paths line by line.

The `${file/%id_*.txt/id_$i}` expression [substitutes](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html#SUBSTRREPL03) `id_$i` for `id_*.txt`.

And the next line (`(( ++i ))`) is an arithmetic expression that increments the `i` variable.

Note, if you want to restrict the effect of the script to some directory level, use `find`'s `-maxdepth` option.

Answer (score 0):

If the files are in the format you provide in your question, this should work-

```
#Get the number of .txt. files to be renamed    
    num=$(ls id_*.txt | wc -l) 
#Rename them
    for i in $(seq 1 "$num")
    do
        mv id_"$num"000.txt id_"$num".txt
    done
```

Do a dry run in a test folder before you run it on the actual files.

Comment: but the numbers may be random

Comment: @J.Carter you should have made your question reflect that randomness. Anyway, I'm happy you got an answer that works for you.